# CSS scrollbar in fixed modal window

Tags: css

I have a simple modal window which I have made that contains a list of personnel in a dabase. The issues is as it is fixed modal window, when I dynamically add more names to the list, the dialog box extends outside the browser window view, but the scroll bars do not activate? How do I get the scrollbars to show once it extends over the view of the window? I've place photos of my predicament below and the CSS. I appreciate any advice people may have in address this issue.

[image]
[image]

And my CSS for the modalwindow:

```
.modalPersonResp{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left:25%;
    height:auto;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left:0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks I used this for solution below.

Comment: Please add the HTML so this makes sense for future users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a fixed height and adjusting the overflow setting in your CSS should correct the behaviour:

```
.modalPersonResp{
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left:25%;
    height:80%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-left:0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```